# why css loader not working with npm run eject on react 16.6

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

When I run

```
npm run eject
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

How can I fix this?

Comment: post your config, otherwise we can't use a crystal ball to know it.

Comment: and write your post in more detail (see [mcve]). I've edited it to give you an idea what it may look like, but we still need the config to help you. Usually, when seeking debugging help, you also should describe the expected behaviour